# Bug in transcribe

Tags: multi-language, transcribe

I am using EE v 2.8.1 and Transcribe 1.6 and I am getting a warning on one page as

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Division by zero

Filename: transcribe/ext.transcribe.php

Line Number: 472

Can anyone please help me out here

Cheers
Nisar

Answer (score 2):

Just emailed a fix over to you!

Comment: Are you able to provide a link to the modified files or give information about which release the fix will be rolled into?

Comment: This will be included in the next release!

Comment: Also just updated to 2.8.1 and getting the same error, are you able to email over the fix to us as well please?